# MySQL REGEXP matching only subdirectories of given directory

Tags: mysql, regex

Consider database entries, having path written as:

```
Lost & Found\Folder2039937\
   |   Lost & Found\Folder2039909\Folder3012231

Lost & Found\Folder2039909\
   |    Lost & Found\Folder2039909\Folder3012111
```

(visuals added to clarify structure)

Those are not related by any foreign key, so thats the only thing I've got to work on, sadly.

Now, given *Lost & Found* path, I need to query MySQL for ANY DIRECT subdirectories of path Lost & Found. So the result should be:

```
Lost & Found\Folder2039937\
Lost & Found\Folder2039909\
```

but no

```
Lost & Found\Folder2039937\Folder3012231
Lost & Found\Folder2039909\Folder3012111
```

I've got no idea, how I could do this using MySQL query. What I've tried is writting *REGEXP* to get those entries, but I can't figure out the right expression. I've tried multiple combinations, but I'm totally new to REGEXP and never had requirement for using REGEXP.

Is REGEXP the only way I could do this? If yes, what would be the right one?

Comment: Have you tried `REGEXP 'Lost & Found\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\?$'`?

Comment: @Siguza Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Post as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using REGEX, something like:

```
select *
from paths
where path regexp '^Lost & Found\\\\([^\\]+)\\\\?$'
;
```

Note the repetitive `\\\\` - there needs to be two levels since `\\` is used to escape `\` at both the string level and the regex level.

Here is the documentation for MySQL's REGEXP: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an interesting alternative:

```
select path
from (
    select
        path,
        substring_index(path, '\\', 1) as part1,
        substring_index(substring_index(path, '\\', 2), '\\', -1) as part2
    from paths
) t
where part1 = 'Lost & Found'
    and part2 <> ''
    and length(concat(part1, part2)) + 1 = length(trim(trailing '\\' from path))
;
```

You could split on the slashes and match the pieces. It gets a bit messy then trying to check whether there are exactly two pieces. There might be a better way to do that but this was the first thing I could think of. It takes the length of part1 and 2, adds 1 for the slash between them, and compares that to the length of the entire path with trailing slash removed (making it optional).

I have found SUBSTRING_INDEX to be very useful in the past when dealing with delimited text, and MySQL definitely has a great selection of other string manipulation functions as well, they just tend to get very long since it's difficult to "save" any intermediate pieces.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Technique is interesting, bringing string manipulations a bit closer to me, but giving each project containing around 460.000 rows containing file information,and take into consideration APP will have multiple active projects, resulting few million entries at given time in table, this query runs like 3 times slower than using REGEXP. Altho thanks for bringing this up, interesting way to manipulate delimited texts, but in my case won't work that well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `like`:

```
where path like 'Lost & Found\\%' and
      path not like 'Lost & Found\\%\\%'
```

I am not sure which is faster in general.  But, the `like` expression *can* take advantage of indexes because it does not start with a wildcard.  So, under some circumstances, it could be much faster.

Comment: This does not work my friend. Produces empty results in my database.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from path where (file REGEXP 'Lost & Found\\\\([^\\]+)\\\\([^\\]+)\\\\?$' OR file REGEXP 'Lost & Found\\\\([^\\]+)\\\\?$')`

this gets the result first level `files` and `folders`